# How can i check if the input is in English language

Tags: python

How can I check if the input is letters not numbers and only the English language?

```
f="Hello"
print f.isalpha()
True


f="Hello5"
print f.isalpha()
False


f="اهلا"
print f.isalpha()
True
```

I want it to be True only when f is letters in English and without numbers, like this:

```
f="اهلا"
print f.isalpha()
False


f="Hello"
print f.isalpha()
True
```

Comment: Checking if it contains only ASCII letters and punctuation is easy. Checking if it is English is not.

Comment: The alphabet which this letters belong to is called Latin, not English. There are many other languages besides English that use those letters.

Answer (score 4):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
str_a = "abc"
str_b = "اهل"
print re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+\Z', str_a) is not None # True
print re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]+\Z', str_b) is not None # False
```

Comment: Your regexp also accepts an optional trailing newline (`'\n'`). To avoid accepting that, replace `$` with `\\Z` (or use `r'^[a-zA-Z]+\Z'`).